# What is difference between tf.truncated_normal and tf.random_normal?

Tags: math, machine-learning, tensorflow

`tf.random_normal(shape, mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32, seed=None, name=None)` outputs random values from a normal distribution.

`tf.truncated_normal(shape, mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32, seed=None, name=None)` outputs random values from a truncated normal distribution.

I tried googling 'truncated normal distribution'. But didn't understand much.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

The [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/truncated_normal) says it all:
For truncated normal distribution:

> The values are drawn from a normal distribution with specified mean and standard deviation, discarding and re-drawing any samples that are more than two standard deviations from the mean.

Most probably it is easy to understand the difference by plotting the graph for yourself (%magic is because I use jupyter notebook):

```
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline  

n = 500000
A = tf.truncated_normal((n,))
B = tf.random_normal((n,))
with tf.Session() as sess:
    a, b = sess.run([A, B])
```

And now

```
plt.hist(a, 100, (-4.2, 4.2));
plt.hist(b, 100, (-4.2, 4.2));
```

[image]

---

The point for using truncated normal is to overcome saturation of tome functions like sigmoid (where if the value is too big/small, the neuron stops learning).

Comment: thanks for the code. It is great. however, i can't print out histogram on the pc as shown below. Do you know why? ,>>> plt.hist(b,100,(-4.2,4.2));
(array([  3.00000000e+00,   6.00000000e+00,   9.00000000e+00,
         4.00000000e+00,   1.60000000e+01,   8.00000000e+00,
        3.864,  3.948,  4.032,  4.116,  4.2  ]), <a list of 100 Patch objects>)

Comment: @Hong sorry, but I have no idea why. It looks like it was calculated but for some reason is not plotted. May be you can ask a question related to matplotlib

Comment: @SalvadorDali A question following this one would be then, when is one more preferred than the other? It seems to me that truncated_normal is more often than not the preferred option. When is random_normal a valid choice?

Comment: @CarlosJimenezBermudez it is hard to predict which initialization will lead to the fastest learning. random_normal might be used with RELU activations. The reason for not-using random_normal is saturations for sigmoid/tanh, but they are not frequently used now.

Answer (score 25):

`tf.truncated_normal()` selects random numbers from a normal distribution whose mean is close to 0 and values are close to 0. For example, from -0.1 to 0.1. It's called truncated because your cutting off the tails from a normal distribution.

`tf.random_normal()` selects random numbers from a normal distribution whose mean is close to 0, but values can be a bit further apart. For example, from -2 to 2.

In machine learning, in practice, you usually want your weights to be close to 0.

Comment: In ML, the usual suggestion is that weights have a mean of 0, standard deviation of 0.1 or 0.01, be close to 0 and have a uniform distribution. 
Can you tell exactly why ?

Comment: @pravbeatle I believe this post can help you, http://cs231n.github.io/neural-networks-2/. Those values are preferred because the network will train faster.

Comment: @pravbeatle another explanation of weight saturation for sigmoid link: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228670/what-is-the-benefit-of-the-truncated-normal-distribution-in-initializing-weights

Answer (score 8):

The [API documentation for tf.truncated_normal()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/truncated_normal) describes the function as:

> Outputs random values from a truncated normal distribution.
>
> The generated values follow a normal distribution with specified mean and standard deviation, except that values whose magnitude is
> more than 2 standard deviations from the mean are dropped and
> re-picked.