# Tensorflow: weights aren't changing and cost set to 1.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, gradient-descent

I tried to build a convolutional neural network but I have stumbled over some really strange problems.

first thing's first, here's my code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import glob

x = []
y = 1

for filename in glob.glob('trainig_data/*.jpg'):
    im = mpimg.imread(filename)
    x.append(im)
    if len(x) == 10:
        break
epochs = 5

weights = [tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,3,32],0.1)),
           tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,32,64],0.1)),
           tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([5,5,64,128],0.1)),
           tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([75*75*128,1064],0.1)),
           tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1064,1],0.1))]

def CNN(x, weights):
    output = tf.nn.conv2d([x], weights[0], [1,1,1,1], 'SAME')
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    output = tf.nn.conv2d(output, weights[1], [1,2,2,1], 'SAME')
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    output = tf.nn.conv2d(output, weights[2], [1,2,2,1], 'SAME')
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    output = tf.reshape(output, [-1,75*75*128])
    output = tf.matmul(output, weights[3])
    output = tf.nn.relu(output)
    output = tf.matmul(output, weights[4])
    output = tf.reduce_sum(output)
    return output


sess = tf.Session()
prediction = CNN(tf.cast(x[0],tf.float32), weights)
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.square(prediction-y))
train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.01).minimize(cost)
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()

sess.run(init)
for e in range(epochs):
    print('epoch:',e+1)
    for x_i in x:
        prediction = CNN(tf.cast(x_i,tf.float32), weights)
        sess.run([cost, train])
        print(sess.run(cost))
print('optimization finished!')
print(sess.run(prediction))
```

Now here are my problems:

1. The values of the weights and filters are not changing
2. The variable 'cost' is always 1.0
3. The prediction always puts out a 0

After doing some debugging I found out that the problem must come from the optimizer, because the cost and the prediction are not 1.0 and 0 before I put the weights trough the optimizer.

I hope that was enough information and that you can help me with my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the way you initialise weights, use [tf.truncated_normal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/truncated_normal) to initialise weights. Refer [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43726140/6633975), which states difference between tf.truncated_normal.

[tf.truncted_normal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/truncated_normal): Outputs random values from a truncated normal distribution. The generated values follow a normal distribution with specified mean and standard deviation, except that values whose magnitude is more than 2 standard deviations from the mean are dropped and re-picked.

[tf.random_normal](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random_normal): Outputs random values from a normal distribution.

Comment: that didn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

the code seems to be odd. in the last line of your CNN function, you used the tf.reduce_mean to get a single value as an output, which is going to be a positive number (most probably greater than 1) (0, inf) as relu activation function output a positive value only for inputs lying on the positive x-axis. so, i think you should use tf.nn.softmax_with_logits() instead of tf.reduce_mean. Also try with using sigmoid activation function.